# Different matrices with same determinant and same numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to know example of two matrices that:

1) contain the same natural numbers greater than zero( sequences of all numbers of these matrices ordered by size are exactly the same)

2) One matrix can't be obtained from the other using column/row swaps (so when I swap i-th and j-th row, I also swap i-th and j-th column).

3) Are bigger than 3x3

4) Determinants of these matrices are equal.

Sorry for adding it now, but I also need those matrices to be equivalent with their transposes. Or if anyone could give me example of two non-isomorphic simple graphs, that have distance matrices with same determinant.

Comment: Is this problem coming from somewhere else? If so, I'm suspicious of "so when I swap i-th and j-th row, I also swap i-th and j-th column" - that is not the usual interpretation of "using column/row swaps" in mathematics.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot one point to write down, both matrices has to be equal to their transpose. My actual effort is to find two non-isomorphic simple graphs, that have distance matrices with same determinant. True, finding such matrices does not mean finding such graphs, but it is helpful.

Comment: In this case, a new answer has already been added, but for future reference, changing a question after posting it is discouraged. Lord_Farin has good advice about situations like this here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9746/26369

Comment: Any thoughts about my answer, TStancek?

Comment: Earth to TStancek: come in, please.

Answer (score 2):

$$\pmatrix{2&2&1&1&1\cr2&1&1&1&1\cr1&1&1&1&1\cr1&1&1&1&1\cr1&1&1&1&1\cr}\qquad\pmatrix{2&1&1&1&1\cr1&1&2&1&1\cr1&2&1&1&1\cr1&1&1&1&1\cr1&1&1&1&1\cr}$$

Answer (score 1):

I believe that
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
13 & 14 & 15 & 16
\end{bmatrix} $$
and
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 5 & 9 & 13 \\
2 & 6 & 10 & 14 \\
3 & 7 & 11 & 15 \\
4 & 8 & 12 & 16
\end{bmatrix} $$
is one such pair.  Note one is the transpose of the other, so their determinants are equal.  You can extrapolate this answer to matrices of larger sizes too.

Comment: Brilliant!!!!! +1